# Web service and Azure - How do I consume the web service with React?

Tags: reactjs, azure, web-services, web

I wrote a web service in Visual Basic using Visual Studio Community 2015.  The code I wrote will make a mySql connection to a mySql data base hosted on the cloud by mySql.  The code works correctly and pulls the required data from the mySql database.  I tested it locally on my development machine.

I them published the code using the publish wizard.  When the wizard first opened, I selected a publish target (Microsoft Azure Web Apps) and clicked ok.  The next screen asked me to enter a web app name, app service plan, resource group, region, and database server.  I entered all the information and clicked create.

After a while, I got a message that said something to the effect that my subscription type is not allowed in the region I selected.  However, when I log into my Azure account, and go to my portal, I see an entry called appServicewmcw (which is the name of the app I entered when publishing) and to the right is says App Service Plan.

When I click on the app, I get a page which gives me the following information:

> Resource group: resourceGroupwmcw
>
> Status: Running
>
> Location: East US
>
> Subscription: Free Trial
>
> Subscription ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> URL: https://webservicewmcw.azurewebsites.net
>
> App Service plan/pricing tier: appServicewmcw
>
> FTP/deployment username: No FTP/deployment user set
>
> FTP hostname: ftp://waws-prod-blu-099.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net
>
> FTPS hostname: ftps://waws-prod-blu-099.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net

So, my question is, how do I call (consume?) this web service and display the data the service is returning?  I am trying to write the code in React to display on a page.  The code I am using would be something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let appTitle_literal = "Title Not Found";
let appDescription_literal = "Description Not Found";

{
    call the web service
    if the web service returns data then
        let returned_data = web_service_returned_data
        let rData = returned_data.split("|")
        appTitle_literal = rData[0]
        appDescription_literal = rData[1]
}

const appTitle_element = React.createElement('div', null, appTitle_literal);
const appDescription_element = React.createElement('div', null, appDescription_literal);

ReactDOM.render(appTitle_element, document.getElementById('appTitle'));
ReactDOM.render(appDescription_element, document.getElementById('appDescription'));
```

Comment: You could experiment with the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API.

Comment: have you exposed the endpoint that fetches data in a restful fashion ? e.g.  hostname/getcustomers/customerId

Comment: I think my biggest question is what url do I use to call the service I uploaded.  I have since re-published the service and now when I look at the Azure dashboard, the url listed is https://wmcwwebservice.azurewebsites.net.  When I place this url into postman, the returned xml is not the data my webservice returns but the response from Azure telling me "Your App Service app is up and running" along with other Welcome information from Microsoft.  So I still do not know what url to enter into the fetch().